# What are the components inside ADC and DAC?

Tags: adc, integrated-circuit, components, logic-gates, dac

My question is this: What are the components inside ADC and DAC?

Is there only transistors/logical gates and is there difference between like analog audio to digital audio ADC or other types of ADC integrated circuits?

Comment: There’s many ways to make DACs and ADCs. If you want a specific answer, you need to give us a specific example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No differences - both DACs and ADCs can be constructed of resistors, capacitors, and transistors. And, of course, some wire and a power supply.

But there are numerous different conversion principles which need different components. If you for ex. have already a proper digital 8 bit parallel output port in a computer and your program outputs a binary number to it, a not so high accuracy DAC which makes it to a current which is proportional to the number can be made by connecting together only some resistors. Some resistors more and few transistors are needed to convert it to a voltage.

An ADC which converts a voltage to a binary number which can be red to a computer through a 8 bit parallel port as a single byte needs much more. Probably the total count of all needed transistors, resistors and capacitors is hundreds. For that reason I have used only ready to use analog to digital converter ICs or tried to let the computer software to use a DAC and a voltage comparator to find which binary number is the closest one.

Different signals need different conversion principles. An ADC which takes say a gigasample per a second in an oscilloscope surely is quite different than what's needed to digitize phone quality audio say 8000 samples per a second. And that's again quite different what's needed to digitize high resolution low noise audio in a studio recording system (24 bit, 96 ksamples per a second). I guess you should do some systematic studies of electronics to see it also by yourself.

Comment: Thank you, maybe this clarified things a bit, although I still don't quite understand why e.g. capacitors are needed in this circuit, I'm specifically interested in circuits that convert analog audio to digital one and vice versa.